# Cannot initialize S3 history archive - unable to locate credentials

Tags: stellar-core, history

I am trying to initialize an S3 bucket as history for stellar core using this command:

```
stellar-core new-hist s3
```

this is my [history.s3] config:

```
[HISTORY.s3]
get="aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/history/{0} -o {1}"
put="aws s3 cp {0} s3://mybucket/history/{1}"
```

I also have confirmed that I configured AWS CLI with the configuration of Key and Secret but when I run the command I get this response:

[Process WARNING] process 103886 exited 1: aws s3 cp buckets/tmp/history-0ccaccb182270f27/926834ff2623c8d0-stellar-history.json s3://mybucket/history/.well-known/stellar-history.json
[Process WARNING] process 103887 exited 1: aws s3 cp buckets/tmp/history-0ccaccb182270f27/926834ff2623c8d0-stellar-history.json s3://mybucket/history/history/00/00/00/history-00000000.json
upload failed: buckets/tmp/history-0ccaccb182270f27/926834ff2623c8d0-stellar-history.json to s3://mybucket/history/.well-known/stellar-history.json **Unable to locate credentials**
upload failed: buckets/tmp/history-0ccaccb182270f27/926834ff2623c8d0-stellar-history.json to s3://mybucket/history/history/00/00/00/history-00000000.json **Unable to locate credentials**

Answer (score 0):

After backtracking my steps. I figured out that I needed to enter the AWSCLI configurations in root (sudo -s). Checking in root I found that the config was still empty.